# Managing depth in actionscript3

Tags: flash, 3d, actionscript-3

I have a `3D` field with many `MovieClip`s in it, and seems like the one last added is the one  that overlaps others and not the one with highest `z` value.
Is there any property/function that sets `z-index`? (sorting children by `z` value seems too much like a hack).
A `3D` engine that can place `MovieClip`s will be helpful(but not one that requires custom drawing).
I'm using `Flash CS5` with `ActionScript 3`

Answer (score 2):

You need this helper class:

http://blog.theflashblog.com/?p=470

Comment: Can you expand on the answer a little bit?